# Print prepared dynamic query with result set in Postgresql function using DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, postgresql-12

I have the function in which I have prepared dynamic query, which I want print in output window before executing it.

**Note**: In the following example I have just add simple select statement to understand the requirement.

Sample tables:

```
create table t1
(
col1 int,
col2 text
);
insert into t1 values(1,'Table T1');
insert into t1 values(2,'Table T1');

create table t2
(
col1 int,
col2 text
); 
insert into t2 values(1,'Table T2');
insert into t2 values(2,'Table T2');
```

Function:

```
create or replace function fn_testing(tbl_Name text)
returns table(col1 int,col2 text) as 
$$
begin
   return query execute 'select col1,col2 from '||tbl_name||'';
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Function call:

```
select * from fn_testing('t2');
```

I want to print following in message window with result set too in result window:

```
select col1,col2 from t1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RAISE NOTICE` for messages.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_testing
                           (_tbl_name name)
                           RETURNS TABLE
                                   (col1 integer,
                                    col2 text)
AS
$$
DECLARE
  _query text;
BEGIN
  _query := format('SELECT col1, col2 FROM %I;', _tbl_name);
  RAISE NOTICE '%', _query;
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _query;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note: There's a special type, `name`, for identifiers. And to prevent SQL injection or errors you should make sure the dynamic identifiers are properly quoted. You can use `format()` with `%I` for that.